# How I can call a static method in a generic class on flutter?

Tags: flutter, generics

How I can call a static method in a generic class on flutter? I try to do a simple example

```
///
class A {
  ///
  static void test(){}
}

///
class F<T extends A> {
  ///
  void test() {
    T.test(); // <- error: flutter don't know the method
  }
  
}
```

How I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, it is not possible. Subclasses do not inherit static methods.

Since subclasses do not inherit and therefore can not override the static method, you can just call `A.test()`. If you do need to override the method in a subclass of `A`, you'll have to use an instance method.